# Postgresql. Выбрать записи, убрав повторяющиеся по определенному полю

Tags: sql, postgresql

Есть таблица вот с такими полями:

```
id, group, filter_param1, filter_param2, sort_param1
```

Я делаю вот такой запрос:

```
SELECT * FROM table 
WHERE filter_param1 = value1 
  AND filter_param2 = value2 
ORDER BY sort_param1 
DESC LIMIT 50
```

В результате я получаю нужные мне записи, но одно НО. Нужно выбрать записи так, чтобы значения поля `group` не повторялось в результате.

Пробовал добавить в запрос `DISTINCT` и `DISTINCT ON`, но они требуют чтобы в `ORDER BY` было поле `group`, что сразу сбивает основную сортировку по полю `sort_param1`.

Пробовал использовать `GROUP BY`, но в постгресе он работает не так как в MySQL.

Как можно выбрать записи удовлетворяющие такому условию? Записи должны быть выбраны по полям `filter_param1, filter_param2`, значения поля `group` должно быть уникальным, отсортированы полю `sort_param1` по убыванию и в количестве 50 записей.

Comment: Вы бы пример данных привели. Если group будет только один, то какой filter_param1 и 2 рядом с ним должен быть написан ? Я же правильно понял, что с одним group может быть несколько разных filter. И какой sort_param актуален, при сортировке, если например есть group 1 с записями sort=1 и 5, и group 2 с sort 2,3,8 вот какой из group надо делать первым ?

Comment: filter_param1 и 2 не сильно важен. Основная задача выбрать записи с неповторяющимся полем group. Приведу аналогию с реальной задачей. В интернет-магазине нужно вывести товары, так сказать по одному из каждой группы, при этом отсортировав их по цене по убыванию. В данном случае у меня выводятся товары больше чем по одному из кадой группы

Comment: А какое нибудь пожелание, какой именно товар из группы выдать есть ?  тупо с минимальным id например не проблема. И цена даже именно этого товара будет. Но боюсь это немного не то, что требуется.

Comment: В общем если товар с минимальным id из группы подойдет - то `select * from table where id in(SELECT min(id) FROM table 
WHERE filter_param1 = value1 
  AND filter_param2 = value2 GROUP BY "group") order by sort_param1 
DESC LIMIT 50` - такой результат устроит ?

Comment: Получается должен быть самый дорогой товар из группы. И кстати групп очень много, поэтому составлять список групп и по нему выбирать самые дорогие товары будет нерациональным решением

Comment: К сожалению, нет. В любой момент может появится более дорогой товар с другим id

Comment: Хорошо, значит точно условие "самый дорогой товар из группы" и предположим условие "заранее ограничить группы". Как их ограничить ? группы то же с самыми дорогими товарами ? потому как запрос уже непрост и есть поле для выбора - группы с минимальной стоимостью самого дорогого в группе товара например ...

Comment: В этом запросе про группы нам ничего не известно, все равно какая группа, но в результате она должна быть одна.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select *
    from (
        select *,rank() over (partition by "group" order by sort_param1 desc) n
        from table
        where filter_param1 = value1 AND filter_param2 = value2 
    ) A where n=1
order by sort_param1
limit 50
```

Правда мы не уточнили брать максимальную цену среди найденых товаров или в целом по группе. Сейчас в запросе сделано "среди найденных".

Основа запроса в функции `rank()` которая нумерует (1,2,3,...) записи в пределах группы, заданной `partition by` предложения `over`, в порядке, заданном `order by` в `over`. Последующее условие во внешнем запросе n=1 говорит брать только первые записи в группе, которыми окажутся с максимальным sort_param1. Если надо, например выбрать, по 2-3 товара из каждой группы, можно написать `n<=3`. Внешний `order by` запроса в принцип никак не связан с тем, что в `rank() over()`.

Comment: Да, это как раз то что надо. Можете подробнее рассказать что происходит в этой строке? `rank() over (partition by "group" order by sort_param1 desc)`

Comment: @DimaGvozdev  Написал в ответе. Погоняйте внутренний запрос отдельно, для наглядности, увидите как она нумерует