# Вывести строки а не столбцы

Tags: sql

distinct выводит уникальные столбцы, как вывести строки где они нашлись?

Comment: поподробнее вопрос раскройте. потому как distinct выдает уникальные наборы значений столбцов - которые представляют собой как раз те самые строки. приведите пример данных что дает distinct на каких данных и что вы хотите получить в ответе. И самое главное, на каком диалекте sql это нужно. У меня ощущение, что требуемое вами проще всего делается оконными функциями, которых например в mysql нет

Comment: Вопрос совсем непонятен. DISTINCT в SELECT-е как бы откидывает повторяющиеся данные в запросе, ничего уникального он не выводит. И при чем тут столбцы? Вы бы хоть запрос приложили к вопросу, а чем речь то идет?

Comment: Есть таблица: id, name, action . Запрос select distinct action from table выведет только уникальные данные по action, а хотелось бы все 3 столбца.

Comment: Стандартный вопрос: а что должно быть около конкретного action какой id и какой name, если их несколько

Comment: А стандартный, потому что позавчера был подобный вопрос http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/488441/postgresql-%D0%92%D1%8B%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B8-%D1%83%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8F%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8E/488455#488455  И если посмотрите переписку, то поймете насколько больше нужно дать данных для правильного решения. И какой именно sql все таки укажите

Comment: первый попавшийся action, можно по условию < id

Comment: что значит первый попавшийся. select distinct вам давал уникальные action. т.е. по одному action. И к этому одному action может быть несколько id. И чем не подходит `select * from table group by action` Правда если у вас не mysql то от всех устолбцов не участвующих в group by надо брать агрегатные функции, например min(id) для минимального id для данного action

Comment: Как вариант: SELECT DISTINCT ON(action) table.* FROM "table"; Это работает для PostgreSQL.

Comment: Всем спасибо! Решаю дальше =).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

При условии, что `id` уникален:

```
SELECT id, name, action
FROM table
WHERE id = ANY(
    SELECT min(id)
        FROM table
        GROUP BY action
    )
```

Comment: То что надо =)!!!

Comment: Плохой с точки зрения эффективности запрос. Нет необходимости делать подзапрос(второе чтение из table) в данном случае. Задача должна решаться и решается проще.

Comment: _SELECT MIN(id)id, MIN(name)name, action
FROM table
GROUP BY action_ не сохраняет целостность. _SELECT id, name, action
FROM(
  SELECT MIN(id)OVER(PARTITION BY action)min_id, *
  FROM table
)T WHERE id = min_id_ - оконные функции, в данном случае, еще более неэффективны. особенно если есть index по id ( что, я думаю, очевидно ).

Comment: тест ( удаленный postgresql9.4 с таблицей в 50000 записей ) с group by - 35mc, с оконной функцией - 80mc.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT MIN(id)id, MIN(name)name, action
FROM table
GROUP BY action
```

Или если надо, чтобы id соответствовал name, тогда:

```
SELECT id, name, action
FROM(
  SELECT MIN(id)OVER(PARTITION BY action)min_id, *
  FROM table
)T WHERE id = min_id
```